# Adding Spring Boot's CRaSH shell to regular non-boot Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Spring Boot comes with a neat remote monitoring shell (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-remote-shell.html) that's installed into Spring Boot apps by adding spring-boot-starter-remote-shell dependency. It provides access to Spring beans, jdbc, allows extension by custom commands, plugs into Spring Security for authentication, you can connect to it via SSH etc...

I would really like this feature in my regular non-boot Spring MVC application. I've searched the internet and Spring docs and found nothing. Any ideas how to achieve this besides reverse engineering spring-boot-starter-remote-shell sources?

Comment: You can always convert your application to a Spring Boot driven one... But if you don't want that I guess your best move would be to use that starter and incorporate it into your own application (you probably need some additinal registration of configuration etc.).

Comment: http://www.crashub.org/1.3/reference.html#_embedding_in_a_web_app seems to suggest you just wire one of the beans from crash into your existing Spring application context.  The fact that the provided beans are Spring Boot based doesn't necessarily mean your app has to be.